# Unable to publish on Jitpack: Execution failed for task ':install'

Tags: github, gradle, kotlin, dependencies, jitpack

Well, I'm since about 4 hours trying to publish my project on JitPack, but I always get the same error:

> Execution failed for task ':install'.

I searched a lot, but nothing was found about it.

Log: https://jitpack.io/com/github/NathanPB/DogoAPI/master-63f1267b6d-1/build.log

Repo: https://github.com/NathanPB/DogoAPI

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently task `:jar is SKIPPED`, so try to run locally `./gradlew jar --info` and check something suspicious in output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking on the log, [luX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/647381/rux) told me that the `jar` task was skipped:

> :jar SKIPPED

Then, I modified my `build.gradle` from

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'cf.dogo.api.DogoAPIKt'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } 
    }
}
```

To

```
jar {
    enabled = true
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'cf.dogo.api.DogoAPIKt'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } 
    }
}
```

Adding `enabled = true` for `jar` task. Everything worked very well after that.